# REGEXP_SUBSTR for portion of string

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I would like to get:

`82961_01B04WZXQQSUGJ4YMRRT2A7TRHK_MR_2_1of1`

from the following expression

`LASTNAME_FIRSTNAME_82961_01B04WZXQQSUGJ4YMRRT2A7TRHK_MR_2_1of1`

Does someone know how I can get this using regexp_substr ?

**EDIT**

Basically I have a field which has 7 sets each separated by _ . The string I gave is just one example. I wanted to retrieve everything after the second _ . There is no fixed character length so I can not use a substr function. Hence I was using regexp_substr. I was able to get away by using a simplified version

```
Select FILE_NAME, (  (REGEXP_SUBSTR(FILE_NAME,'[^_]+_',1,3)) || 
                      (REGEXP_SUBSTR(FILE_NAME,'[^_]+_',1,4)) || 
                      (REGEXP_SUBSTR(FILE_NAME,'[^_]+_',1,5)) ||
                      (REGEXP_SUBSTR(FILE_NAME,'[^_]+_',1,6)) || 
                      (REGEXP_SUBSTR(FILE_NAME,'[^_]+',1,7))  ) as RegExp
             from tbl
```

Here is some more data from the FILE_NAME field

```
LAST_FIRST_82961_01B04WZXQQSUGJ4YMRRT2A7TRHK_MR_2_1of1
SMITH_JOHN_82961_0130BPQX9QZN9G4P5RDTPA9HR4R_MR_1_1of1
LASTNAME_FIRSTNAME_99999_01V0MU4XUQK0Y24Y9RYTFA7W1CM_MR_3_1of1
```

Comment: What logic you need to realize? Do you need to remove the part 'LASTNAME_FIRSTNAME_'? The first two "words" with the underscore as separator? everything up to the second underscore, ... ? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

To get everything after the second underscore, you do not need regular expressions, but can use something like the following:

```
 select substr(FILE_NAME, instr(FILE_NAME, '_', 1, 2) +1 ) from tbl
```

The `instr` returns the position of the second occurrence of '_', starting by the first character; the `substr` simply gets everything starting from the position given by `instr` + 1

Answer (score 0):

From your Requirement, you can just go ahead and use the simple `SUBSTR`function. Its faster, and it addresses the simple need to remove the String `LASTNAME_FIRSTNAME`.

```
select  substr('LASTNAME_FIRSTNAME_82961_01B04WZXQQSUGJ4YMRRT2A7TRHK_MR_2_1of1', 20) data_string
from    dual;
```

Output:

```
data_string
-----------------
82961_01B04WZXQQSUGJ4YMRRT2A7TRHK_MR_2_1of1
```

Unless you have another underlying logic you need to address?
Kindly clarify so i can edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I am sorry I did not explain this in more detail. Basically I have a field.